# Data integrity errors in google cloud dataflow jobs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I've noticed one of my dataflow jobs has produced output with what I could best describe as too many random bit flips. For example a year "2014" (as text) was written as "0007" or "2016" or "0052" or other textual values. In some cases the output line format is valid (which suggests something happened in processing) but few lines seems to have malformed formatting as well (e.g., "20141215-04-25" instead of something like "2014-12-25").

I'm occasionally re-running the jobs with the same code and different date range parameters, and for this specific dates range the job was completing successfully until about a week ago. I have been trying different machine configurations though (4 cpus and 1-cpu instances) and the problems seems to happen more with 4-cpu instances.

Does anybody know what could be leading to this?

Thanks,
G

Comment: Hi G B, let me follow up on this behavior. This is clearly not the intended behavior.

Comment: We've requested more information privately and will post an answer as soon as possible. Thanks, G B!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using 4-cpu instances, Dataflow runs multiple threads in a single Java process. Data corruption could happen if one of the transforms is thread-hostile, that is, not even separate instances of the class can be safely accessed by multiple threads. This typically happens when the class uses a static non-thread-safe member variable.

Comment: Bug in my code indeed :(  Thanks Marian for pinpointing the problem.

Comment: More information about Dataflow's concurrency model is available in this stack overflow [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802802/thread-safely-of-serializablefunction-in-cloud-dataflow)

Answer (score 1):

A thread safety issue in user code resulted in this type of corruption. This type of errors are likely to occur when using multi-core instances for compute.